# Author annotation in VSCode as it is in Jetbrain intelijj idea

Tags: visual-studio-code

What extension to use in VSCode to show author annotation left-hand panel as it is in Jetbrain intelijj idea? (see the pic attached)

[image]

Comment: That is basically who edited that line right? You can use GitLens for that in VSCode.

Comment: @brc-dd thanks for advice, but do you know how to configure GitLens to appear left-hand side as shown on the pic?

Comment: Open command palette (cmd+shift+p) and type "show line history view".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. install [gitlens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens)
2. go to settings, search for `gitlen blame format`, and change format to `${agoOrDate|14-} ${author}` , you can change the format as you like. [customize format](https://github.com/gitkraken/vscode-gitlens/wiki/Custom-Formatting#commit-tokens)
3. Press F1 or cmd+shift+p, search for `toggle File blame`, you can set a shortcut to the command

[image: for example]

Comment: as i know gitlens are not for free... am i wrong ?

Comment: yeah, it is not for free now